# How do i find the number of projects that two employees with specific names that have worked together? (using LIKE operator )

Tags: mysql, function, operators

Let's say I want to find the number of projects the 2 employees Jim Sullivan and Anna Schimdt have worked on together. We have 3 tables employees, workson, project.

**Employees**

| employeeid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 110 | Jim Sullivan |
| 111 | Anna Schimdt |
| 112 | James Lee |

**Workson**

| projectid | employeeid |
| --- | --- |
| 6554 | 110 |
| 6554 | 111 |
| 6555 | 110 |
| 6555 | 111 |
| 6556 | 110 |
| 6556 | 111 |
| 6556 | 112 |

**Projects**

| projectid | projectName |
| --- | --- |
| 6556 | POPS |
| 6555 | BABY |
| 6554 | MAMA |

From the data sample, Jim Sullivan and Anna Schimdt have worked on 3 projects together. Hence expected outcome should be 3. My code does not show any results for some reason. Here is my code:

```
SELECT COUNT(w.employeeid) 
FROM workson w 
JOIN employees e ON e.employeeid = w.employeeid
JOIN projects p ON p.projectid = w.projectid
WHERE name LIKE 'jim%sullivan%'
AND name LIKE 'anna%schmidt%';
```

For some reason, the code works if I only filtered out one employee but as soon as I included both of them, it doesn't work. For example, if I only had Anna Schmidt then results will come out but as soon as I add the AND operator, it does not work. It does work for the OR operator though

Comment: You have only 1 name, and it cannot be `LIKE 'jim%sullivan%'` and also be `LIKE 'anna%schmidt%'`

Comment: So how do I get two employees then ?  Then why does the OR operator seem to work but the AND operator does not

Comment: In your sample date the name is `Schimdt` but in your code you use `schmidt`!

Comment: Haha thanks for spotting the typo. Regardless, my code will not work :)

Comment: @forpas: when collation ends with `_ci` (for case insensitive) It should not matter,  [Schmidt LIKEs schmidt](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7079c6f26d8e59e599546953dcbd8168)

Comment: @Luuk this is not what I mentioned. Read carefully: `Anna Schimdt` in the table and `anna%schmidt%` in the query. `Schim` vs `schmi`

Comment: ok, need coffee  .... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show the projects where Jim did to work on:

```
SELECT 
   p.projectid, 
   p.projectName
FROM Projects p
INNER JOIN Workson w ON w.projectid = p.projectid
INNER JOIN employees e ON e.employeeid = w.employeeid
WHERE e.name LIKE 'jim%sullivan%'
```

When you need the project that share 2 workes, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
   p.projectid, 
   p.projectName
FROM Projects p
INNER JOIN Workson w1 ON w1.projectid = p.projectid
INNER JOIN Workson w2 ON w2.projectid = p.projectid
INNER JOIN Employees e1 ON e1.employeeid = w1.employeeid
INNER JOIN Employees e2 ON e2.employeeid = w2.employeeid
WHERE e1.name LIKE 'jim%sullivan%'
  AND e2.name LIKE 'anna%schmidt%';
```

EDIT: I forgot one JOIN, now it works, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=528618908a9f56e0e22ffb932b9dc887)

Comment: A few errors with your code.  project id is ambiguous. Secondly, I still cant get any answers even after I fixed it. There is no output

Comment: @youfacejaraxxus yet you accepted an answer with 5 table joins when all you need is 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

With this query:

```
SELECT w.projectid
FROM Workson w INNER JOIN Employees e
ON e.employeeid = w.employeeid
WHERE (e.name LIKE 'jim%sullivan%') OR (e.name LIKE 'anna%schmidt%')
GROUP BY w.projectid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

you get all the `projectid`s where Jim Sullivan and Anna Schimdt (or Schmidt) have worked together.
I don't know why you use the operator `LIKE` instead of the operator `=` to compare the column `name` to the names of the employees, so I left it as it is, but this would cause problems if for example there is another employee named 'Annabelle Schmidt'.

Use the above query as a subquery to count the rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count
FROM (
  SELECT w.projectid
  FROM Workson w INNER JOIN Employees e
  ON e.employeeid = w.employeeid
  WHERE (e.name LIKE 'jim%sullivan%') OR (e.name LIKE 'anna%schmidt%')
  GROUP BY w.projectid
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) t;
```

Or, for MySql 8.0+ use `COUNT()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () count
FROM Workson w INNER JOIN Employees e
ON e.employeeid = w.employeeid
WHERE (e.name LIKE 'jim%sullivan%') OR (e.name LIKE 'anna%schmidt%')
GROUP BY w.projectid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4a3d598b0686f86ac038c795f046faf).

The table `Projects` is not needed.